# Retrieve data from RxJS observable in HttpModule

Tags: rxjs, axios, observable, nestjs

I am failing to understand how to `map` the data properties out of `HttpService` in my NestJS application. To my understanding, this `Observable` just wraps `axios`. Here's some example code:

```
interface Todo {
   task: string,
   completed: false
}

import {
  Injectable,
  HttpService,
  Logger,
  NotFoundException,
} from '@nestjs/common'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators

async getTodo(todoUrl: string): Todo {
   const resp = this.httpService
      .get('https://example.com/todo_json')
      .pipe(map(response => response.data)) // map task/completed properties?
   return resp
}
```

`resp` in this case seems to be of type `Observable`. How do I retrieve just the data properties I want using `map` on this request to return my `Todo` interface?

Comment: You have to subscribe to the Observable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nest by default will subscribe to the observable for you it your return the Observable from your service. As this can be the case you can do something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  getTodos(todoUrl: string): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.http.get(todoUrl).pipe(
      map(resp => resp.data),
    );
  }

}
```

And so long as you have a controller class calling `this.todoSerivce.getTodos(todoUrl)` and returning it, the response will be sent out.

However, if you want to instead make it a promise as you are more accustomed to them, you can tack on a `.toPromise()` method to the observable chain and now it it awaitable (though it will be slower because it has to wait for the observable to emit its complete event).

Example with `.toPromise()`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  getTodos(todoUrl: string): Todo {
    const myTodo = await this.http.get(todoUrl).pipe(
      map(resp => resp.data),
    ).toPromise();
    return myTodo;
  }

}
```

---

#### Edit 1/20/22

In `RxJS@^7`, `toPromise()` is deprecated and will be removed in `v8`. Instead, you can use `lastValueFrom` to wrap the entire observable

```js
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}

  getTodos(todoUrl: string): Todo {
    const myTodo = await lastValueFrom(this.http.get(todoUrl).pipe(
      map(resp => resp.data),
    ));
    return myTodo;
  }

}
```

Comment: Where in the NestJS documentation does it suggest that the framework subscribes to Observables for you? Also, is there a way to return just the `Todo` with the properties I want without the Observable?

Comment: It talks about it [in the asynchronicity section of the controller](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#asynchronicity). Like I said though, if you just want to return the `Todo` interface without returning the observable, tack on a `.toPromise()` and await the observable, setting it to some constant (you can still do the `map` and `pipe` operations). Then you can just `return myTodo;`. I'll make an update to show further

Comment: This is great. Mind if I ask how to use map to just retrieve the properties I want from `resp`? in this case, task and completed?

Comment: That kinda depends on what is completely sent back by the api, and without that information it's hard to say how to map things down. But, `map` is just a function so you could expand it out to take on a fuller form and do whatever transformations you need

Comment: how do you import `map`?

Comment: @jim `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators' 

async getTodo(todoUrl: string): Todo {
   const resp = this.httpService
      .get('https://example.com/todo_json')
      .pipe(map(response => response.data)) // map task/completed properties?
   return resp
}
```

`getTodo` returns an Observable, not the response. So your return value should be `Observable<Todo>`.

The code should look more like this:

```
  getTodo(): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.http.get<Todo>('https://example.com/todo_json')
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.data),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

EDIT: You can't just return the data from this method because it is asynchronous. It does not have the data yet. The method returns an Observable ... which is basically a contract saying that it will (at some later time) return the data for you.

Comment: I understand it returns an Observable. Maybe I need to make my question more clear - I just want to return a Todo, based on my interface specified in the question. I do not wish to return an Observable. I want to retrieve that data from the Observable and return that instead as the method interface suggests.

Comment: how do you import `map`?

Comment: I updated the example above ... but it looks like someone else already answered your query in the prior answer.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions need to return a promise, you can call toPromise on an observable to return a promise.

```
async getTodo(todoUrl: string): Todo {
   const resp = this.httpService
      .get('https://example.com/todo_json')
      .pipe(map(response => response.data)) // map task/completed properties?
   return resp.toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async getTodo(todoUrl: string): Todo {
    const resp = await this.httpService
      .get('https://example.com/todo_json')
      .toPromise();
    return resp.data;
}
```